# Sony device Xperia XA ADB driver not working

Tags: android, adb, driver, sony, sony-xperia

I download the XA driver in this link. http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-xa-driver/
 But I cannot run my XA in ADB.

I have done the following steps :

1. Plugin my XA in Win7 USB
2. Turn on XA developer mode, turn on USB debugging
3. Select USB config. PTP (and I also tried MTP)
4. Install XA driver in my Win7. Win7 device manager showing Sony
   so0116 ADB interface Driver (I have installed 2 times, 1 for PTP, 1
   for MTP)
5. In my Android sdk tool, I type command "adb devices" and my XA
   didn't show up ( my another testing device is showing)
6. Restart Win7 and XA

Any advice or other work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get it done. But even I don't know how to make it work. Just post whatever I have done and try if you need to.
(Sony Xperia XA, with Win7)

- Install "15 sec adb installer v1.4.2" all to "y/yes" (It recognize my phone as "SAMSUNG Android Phone") (And now you can use adb command
  in C:)
- Turn on Phone, "USB Debug Mode", change USB config. to "PTP" (MTP is used by Xperia Companion in most case, otherwise should also work(didn't try))
- In Win7 device manager, find the phone device ( ! sign if not install
  any drive ), uninstall whatever it is(reboot PC).
- Right click the (! sign), manually choose your driver ((R)->(L)), choose "SAMSUNG Android Phone"(choose whatever it seems to be (but not to choose "ADB interface")). Then you should see and select "Google,Inc."(the good guy) at left side, And "Android ADB Interface"
  at right side.
- In command line (CMD), type "adb kill-server" and "adb devices",
  ensure the device listed is about your phone (BlueStack 
  or other emu. will also show up)

P.S. seems "15 sec adb installer v1.4.2" did some tricks. Go give it a try.